# Displaying a combination of two lists at a time, in JSwing

Tags: java, swing, list

My problem is I have a `List<String>` of Files and `List<InetAddress>` of thier IP Addresses with me. I want to display them TOGETHER i.e. in the form of FILENAME --- IP as a JList in Swing; so that the user understands which file is there at which place (IP Address).
After that I want to use a double click event which would open that file, hence I want them together. How do I do that? Is there any other way than combining the two lists and making a composite list OR by modifying the `DefaultListModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the `String` (or better `File`) and `InetAddress` into a single object and show those objects in *one* `JList` using an appropriate renderer.

For more information see [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) & particularly [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Comment: In case it is not obvious to you, this answer does not mean you have to combine the lists.  The single object representing the file/IP address does not have to have its own string objects, it can refer to the ones in the lists.  You would have a list of these single objects, but the original lists would be intact, and there would not be a separate copy of their contents.  In short, this is a way to do what you ask without the two ways you ask about avoiding (unless you consider this "combining the two lists").